# Nested Future.sequence executes included Futures sequentially

Tags: scala, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I have a future(`doFour`) that is executed and results passed to a flatmap.
Inside the flatmap I execute two more future(*doOne* and *doTwo*) functions expecting them to run on parallel but I see they are running sequentially (2.13). [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DXGwvsANTJKsgfIihoxItg)

Why are `doOne` and `doTwo` not execute in parallel ?

How can I have them to run in parallel ?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object Test {
  def doOne(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("startFirst");      Thread.sleep(3000);     println("stopFirst")
  }

  def doTwo(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("startSecond");      Thread.sleep(1000);      println("stopSecond")
  }


  def doFour(): Future[Unit] = Future {
    println("do 4");     Thread.sleep(1000);     println("done 4")

  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val resOut = doFour().flatMap { a =>

      val futureOperations = Seq(doOne(), doTwo())

      val res = Future.sequence(futureOperations)
      res
    }

    val stream = Await.result(resOut, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Future` becomes eligible for execution as soon as it is created. So this line creates two `Futures` that can potentially be executed:

```
val futureOperations = Seq(doOne(), doTwo())
```

The call to `Future.sequence` will create a new `Future` that **waits** for each of the futures to complete in turn, but they will both already be available for execution by this point in the code.

```
val res = Future.sequence(futureOperations)
```

If you want `Future`s to **start** sequentially you need to use `map/flatMap`:

```
val res = doOne().map( _ => doTwo())
```

With this code `doTwo` will not be called until `doOne` completes (and not at all if `doOne` fails)

The reason that this does not appear to happen in your example is that you are calling a blocking operation in your `Future` which is blocking a thread that would otherwise be used to execute other `Future`s. So although there are two `Future`s available for execution, only one is actually being executed at a time.

If you mark the code as `blocking` it works correctly:

```
import scala.concurrent.blocking

def doOne(): Future[Unit] = Future {
  blocking{println("startFirst");      Thread.sleep(3000);     println("stop First")}
}

def doTwo(): Future[Unit] = Future {
  blocking{println("startSecond");      Thread.sleep(1000);      println("stop Second")}
}
```

See the comments section for details of why the default behaviour is different on different versions, and why you should never make assumptions about the relative execution order of independent `Future`s.

Comment: This code works as expected at 2.12.  I would expect that when the two futures start they will be executed in parallel as we expect from the eagerness of Futures.

Comment: There is a code comment (which doesn't make it into the API) about the change to a default "BatchingExecutor"; it explains the blocking behavior and also the weird ordering: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.2/src/library/scala/concurrent/BatchingExecutor.scala#L50 The PR with discussion https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7470

Comment: You can reach the source link via Batchable https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Batchable.html

Comment: Worth adding that its easy but tedious to create a rando `ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())` rather than the global. I agree it's confusing behavior for the out-of-the-box experience, rather than the highly-tuned use case.

Comment: I understand the change. It does break behavior for anyone upgrading there code to 2.13

Comment: An ExecutionContext makes no guarantee in which order it will execute its Runnables.

Comment: @Tim "A Future starts executing as soon as it is created" — this is actually incorrect as stated. I think what you mean is, “A Future becomes eligible for execution as soon as it is created.” It's important because this difference is precisely what the question is about! `doTwo` is _eligible_ to run immediately, but (on 2.13) _does not run_ until some time later.

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks. I have updated the answer to reflect this and the other comments.